# iOS scroll issues

Tags: ios, iphone, css, mobile-website

I have created a website at the following address http://www.light-union.com/

**Background Info:** The website works as I expect on android, The website problem I am facing, as I see majority of the developers in this world are facing is the incompatible scrolling feature and fixed elements for iPhone and iPad.

I have decided to conform to such restrictions by making the banner be position:absolute to the top and remove the navigation bar on the left side so these bugs can be avoided all together... Unless someone has a solution to these issues that I am unaware of.

**Problem:**
When the user touches one of the buttons in the nav bar, it seems to work at first and scroll to expected location, there is an animation, but when the user scrolls themselves, this is where the problems seem to occur. I understand this seems to be a unanimous fault for people but perhaps this is due to my lack of understanding in iOS rather then iOS itself. This will also render the top banner useless.

This is the main issue though, there exists scrolling elements for the text at the bottom of each back image. For example in the http://www.light-union.com/in/ page, in the bottom section, the text is scrollable but the other sections seem to be hit and miss with the scrolling element, where the middle section is always miss.

**Implementation so far**

```
    .para{
       overflow-y:scroll;
       font-size: 0.8675em;
       height:65%;
       display:block;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
```

This is the css used on the paragraphs where I wish to implement the scrolling feature.

**NOTE:**  For desired result on iOS check android device